# Apache Camel RabbitMQ from queue to queue

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, apache-camel

I have to implement a micro-service which takes a message from a rabbitmq queue, transform it and push it to a rabbitmq exchange.

I am implementing this functionality using Apache Camel RabbitMq and Spring Boot, using Java SDL for Camel.
I am using (for now) a single rabbitmq server, on my machine.
The configuration looks like this:

```
from("rabbitmq://localhost:5672/exchange1?username=guest&password=guest&queue=q1&autoDelete=false");  
.to("rabbitmq://localhost:5672/exchange2?username=guest&password=guest&exchangeType=fanout&skipQueueDeclare=false")
```

The code anove is getting the  message from q1 and it is publishing it again in q1 over and over again. It works just to get a message from a queue and send it (for example) to file, or create a message separately and publish it to the exchange.
Is there any way to make it work as I expect it to do?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Comment: Hello, I use Camel version 2.20.1

Comment: Most likely you need to delete the rabbit headers from the "from" statement so that they are not passed to the "to" statement.

Comment: @Souciance Eqdam Rashti. Your answer is correct. Please create a real answer so I can approve it. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: @GeorgianVladutu, cool, glad it helped. I wrote an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `from()` generates rabbitMQ headers. Unless you manually remove them, they are passed to your `to()`. This will create a mismatch in your connection. Best is to delete the rabbit headers after your `from()` so they don't interfer in your `to()`.

Comment: This did not work for me.  I ran a .removeHeaders("*") between the from() and to() and it still fills up the target queue in the to() instead of simply sending the single message retrieved from the queue in the from().  It's as if it's not autoAcking the message in the source queue, so it keeps re-consuming it.

Comment: Nevermind.  This is user error.  Using the same exchange to create a queue to consume from, and then using that same exchange to send to a queue is also sending to the source queue, thus creating an infinite loop of sorts.  Creating a separate exchange for the target queue to send through is the way to solve this.